# Laravel Follow Unfollow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente sistema de seguidores. No guarda la información en la Base de datos. Lo raro es que no arroja ningun error. Simplemente no funciona el boton. si agrego datos falsos en la base de datos, muestra todo correctamente. Pero no funciona el boton de Follow para que guarde la informacion. Estoy trabajando con Laravel 8.
Modelo User.php:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Models\Post;

use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Followable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    use Followable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'genero',
        'password',
    ];
```

Controller:

```
public function follow(Request $request){


      $user = User::find($request->user_id);
      $response = auth()->user()->toggleFollow($user);


      return response()->json(['success'=>$response]);
  }
```

Blade:

```
<div class="social-info">
                                    <ul class="social-data-block d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between list-inline p-0 m-0">
                                       <li class="text-center pl-3">
                                          <h6>Posts</h6>
                                          <p class="mb-0">{{ $user->posts->count() }}</p>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="text-center pl-3">
                                          <h6>Followers</h6>
                                          <p class="mb-0 tl-follower" >{{ $user->followers()->get()->count() }}</p>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="text-center pl-3">
                                          <h6>Following</h6>
                                          <p class="mb-0">{{ $user->followings()->get()->count() }}</p>
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
```

Custom.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     

            $.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
               }
            });
      
            $('.action-follow').click(function(){    
               var user_id = $(this).data('id');
               var cObj = $(this);
               var c = $(this).parent("div").find(".tl-follower").text();
      
               $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'/u/follow',
                  data:{user_id:user_id},
                  success:function(data){
                     console.log(data.success);
                     if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.success.attached)){
                        cObj.find("strong").text("Follow");
                        cObj.parent("div").find(".tl-follower").text(parseInt(c)-1);
                     }else{
                        cObj.find("strong").text("UnFollow");
                        cObj.parent("div").find(".tl-follower").text(parseInt(c)+1);
                     }
                  }
               });
            });      
      
            });
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Estoy usando el paquete Overtrue. Para el mi error esta en el script pero no logro identificarlo.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Donde esta `toggleFollow`?

Comment: @JuanRivera Antes que nada muchas gracias por responder. La verdad es que me estoy guiando con este tutorial:
https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-58-follow-unfollow-system-example-from-scratch
No se donde deberia colocar el toggleFollow en caso de ser ese el motivo por el cual no se guardan los datos.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que el `use` está fuera de la clase `User`... debería estár adentro para que use el trait adecuado.

Comment: @Pipe Gracias por tu respuesta! creo que ese no es problema porque fijate que lo puse justo arriba del "protected fillable". Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Aclaro que ya fue resulto. era un problema con el csrf token. Saludos y gracias por sus respuestas!